# How to mask specific slices for each row in a tensor

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I'd like to modify specific vectors in a 3D tensor, according to a list of positions (indices):

```
#indices: 1D vector of positions, indices.shape: (k)

mask = np.zeros(k, n, m)
for i in range(k):
  mask[i][indices[i]] = 1
```

This mask will be applied to another 3D tensor (same shape), where I want to preserve specific vectors, and zero out the rest.

What's the best way to construct such a mask in TensorFlow? I can do it with a loop using an assign op, but I'd like to find a more elegant solution. Perhaps using `tf.scatter_nd`?

EDIT: example:

```
>>> mask_before
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]])

>>> indices
array([2, 1, 4])

>>> mask_after
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]]])
```

Comment: please provide sample data sets and your desired data set

Comment: @MaxU, please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One vectorized way would be expanding dimensions and thus leverage `broadcasting` -

```
np.tile((indices[:,None,None] == np.arange(n)[:,None]), m)
```

Sample run -

```
In [755]: # Sample Setup
     ...: indices = np.array([2,3,1])
     ...: 
     ...: k = 3
     ...: n = 4
     ...: m = 2
     ...: mask = np.zeros((k, n, m),dtype=bool)
     ...: for i in range(k):
     ...:     mask[i][indices[i]] = 1

In [756]: out = np.tile((indices[:,None,None] == np.arange(n)[:,None]), m)

In [757]: np.allclose(out, mask)
Out[757]: True
```

To port over to `tensorflow`, we have the counterparts there :

`tf.expand_dims` and `tf.tile`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the corresponding TF code for Divakar's answer:

```
indices = tf.constant([2,1,4])
a1 = tf.expand_dims(indices, axis=1)
a1 = tf.expand_dims(a1, axis=1)
a2 = tf.range(5)
a2 = tf.expand_dims(a2, axis=1)
a3 = tf.equal(a1, a2)
mask = tf.tile(a3, [1,1,4])


>>> tf.cast(mask, dtype=tf.int8)
<tf.Tensor: id=55, shape=(3, 5, 4), dtype=int8, numpy=
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0]],

   [[0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0]],

   [[0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1]]], dtype=int8)>
```